# parse json in coffee script

Tags: json, parsing, coffeescript

I Have this JSON data. I want to parse it using CoffeeScript.
How to access the value of answer?

```
{"options": [{"answer": "Description for xss injection is", "answer_options": 0, "answer_lang": null}]}
```

I have tried this method but failed:

```
for key,value of data
    for k,v in value
          res.send "#{v}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried hard and got this solution. And its worikng :D

```
body={"options": [{"answer": "Description for xss injection is","answer_options":0, "answer_lang": null}]}
data=JSON.parse(body);
for i of  data.options
      counter = data.options[i];
      res.send "#{i} #{counter.answer}";
```

Hope, it helps someone :D

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the json object is stored in a variable called "object":

```
answer = object["options"][0]["answer"] //answer = "Description for xss injection is"
```

another way to access:

```
answer = object.options[0].answer
```